# Blank screen after updating code (Angular-NativeScript)

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am learning NativeScript and I am able to install one of the sample apps without any problems. the emulators work fine after the app is installed. However, after I make any minor changes to the code and save it, the emulator just shows a white screen. I have to restart the emulator to see the changes I made to the code.

This sounds like a problem with Hot Module Replacement. When I run my code using tns run --no-hmr it restarts the app in the emulator and it works fine, but without HMR developing becomes a major pain.

I have checked several questions here on stack overflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279886/white-screen-displayed-after-splashscreen-in-nativescript-ios), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544136/blank-screen-after-splash-screen), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636713/ios-blank-screen-after-splash-and-login)), but I do not see anyone having the same issue I am having.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime is not possible to use HMR; as per the new maintainer of NativeScript, Nathan Walker from nStudio:

> [Just use the `--no-hmr` for the time being.](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8754#issuecomment-671583792)

Feel free to help them! NativeScript accepts PRs, and they are welcome now more than ever!

However, last time I talked with Nathan, I understood that they are working in a WebSockets-based solution to push code to your phone. After all, most of the code changes are difference in Javascript, not in native dependencies.